# Getting OpenGL to render texture to screen

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, sdl, opengl-2.0

I am having trouble getting an image texture to render to the screen. Nothing is displayed other than a blank black screen, and there are no obvious errors. I believe the issue has something to do with the `glOrtho` call, but i'm not sure.

All relevant code is included below. (OnResize gets called after initialisation and before first Render call)

OpenGL2.1 compatibility required, with a view to add shaders later. The texture stuff being hardcoded to the renderer is just temporary, I already have a texture class ready to go, once I work out what's wrong.

I think I might need a FrameBuffer object somewhere? The tutorials I've found often differ drastically and are usually targeting OGL3

```
Video::Video() : running(true)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::string err = "Error initialising video: ";
        err += SDL_GetError();
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    int flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED;

    this->window = SDL_CreateWindow("lolpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, flags);
    if (this->window == nullptr) {
        std::string err = "Error creating SDL window: ";
        err += SDL_GetError();
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    }

    this->glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(this->window);
    if (this->glcontext == nullptr) {
        std::string err = "Error creating GL context: ";
        err += SDL_GetError();
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    }

    GLenum glew_err = glewInit();
    if (glew_err != GLEW_OK) {
        std::string err = "Error initialising GLEW: ";
        err += (char *)glewGetErrorString(glew_err);
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    }

    if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("OpenGL 2.1 not available");
    }

    int max_tex_size;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &max_tex_size);
    if (max_tex_size < 1024) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Maximum supported texture size too small");
    }

    int max_tex_units;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &max_tex_units);
    if (max_tex_units < 2) {
        throw std::runtime_error("GPU does not have enough texture unnits");
    }

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1); // vsync

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // what's drawn last is displayed on top.




// Temp texture load
        glGenTextures(1, &this->texid);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texid);
        // Set our texture parameters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        // Set texture filtering
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        // Load, create texture and generate mipmaps
        int width, height;
        unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image("awesomeface.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        SOIL_free_image_data(image);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void Video::OnResize(int w, int h)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, 9001, -1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Video::Render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texid);
        // do stuff
    }
    glPopMatrix();


    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(this->window);
}
```

EDIT: Ok, i'm an idiot, I wasn't actually drawing anything. I found that adding the following works, where the `// do stuff` is.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 100, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(100, 100, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(100, 0, 0);
glEnd();
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: You're not really drawing anything. Unless that's where it says "do stuff" in the code.

Comment: hmm. you're probably right. but i don't know what i'm supposed to put there